# Can a judge compel a tech vendor to develop software that can then be used to decrypt data from a device designed by that vendor?

Tags: us-constitution

US federal magistrate Sheri Pym of the US District Court of Central California issued Apple a court order compelling it to give the FBI software that it can use to decrypt the San Bernardino terrorist's iPhone. ([Wired.com news article](http://www.wired.com/2016/02/magistrate-orders-apple-to-help-fbi-hack-phone-of-san-bernardino-shooter/))

Perhaps an important note: The phone in question was an iPhone 5C, which does not have Apple's proprietary "Secure Enclave" chip.

Comment: As a practical matter, the actual cryptography keys involved are held by a few individuals and are most likely tamper resistant. The government's case against Apple was moot from the beginning. If the Apple executives did not capitulate of their own free will, winning the case would be hollow and the keys destroyed before the government could obtain them. Unfortunately, Law is the wrong forum to ask.